# Personnalize route format - Swagger with Play Framework

Tags: java, playframework, routes, swagger

I am developing an API with Swagger UI using Play Framework.

But I got a little problem (not a big problem) : 
My URL are :

```
https://url/find?param1=false&&&param4=1
```

But I have '&&' when a parameter is not given ( I mean param2 and param3)
What I want is simply :

```
https://url/find?param1=false&param4=1
```

Here is : 
My Controller :

```
@Api(value = "url", description = "...")
public class nameClassApiController extends ApiController {

@ApiOperation(value = "...", notes = "...", response = nameClass.class, httpMethod = "GET")
@ApiResponses(value = { @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "success"), @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "error", response = ApiError.class) })


public static Result getList(
@ApiParam(value = "param1", required = false) @QueryParam("param1") Long param1,
@ApiParam(value = "param2", required = false) @QueryParam("param2") Long param2, ....) {

return getJsonSuccessResponse(className.getList(param1, param2, ...));

}
```

And my route definition :

```
GET  url/find  className.getList(param1: java.lang.Long ?= null, param2: java.lang.Long ?= null, param3: java.lang.Long ?= null, param4: java.lang.Long ?= null)
```

NB : Te parameters are optional so in my route I need to put the parameter by default to null.

Any solutions ?
Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by upgrading swagger-UI version to 2.0 (latest)